# JSON_DECODE() not working?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I know its a very silly question but still I have to ask this coz its not working.

I am calling an API...

```
    $service_url = 'http://localhost:8888/ffmobile/signup';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    $curl_post_data = array('email' => $this->params()->fromPost('email'), 'password' => $this->params()->fromPost('password'), 'userName' => $this->params()->fromPost('uname'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

when I am printing the $curl_response..the output is as following

```
{"Error":{"name":"Email Unavailable","message":"Email is already taken. Please choose different email.","code":202},"status":"False","requestId":null}
```

The output is proper but when I am using it like following..

```
$response = json_decode($curl_response, TRUE);
```

and I am printing the $response it does not print anything.

What can be the problem ?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what does this print for you? 
$json = '{"Error":{"name":"Email Unavailable","message":"Email is already taken. Please choose different email.","code":202},"status":"False","requestId":null}';
print_r(json_decode($json, TRUE));

Comment: Its an error given by API..

Comment: i know, just checking if it parses and prints correctly for you. What does that code print for you?

Comment: i want the decoded array but json_decode() not giving anything...

Comment: I understand your problem, it is clear from the question. To further debug this, it would be helpful if you could run that code i posted.

Comment: I am not getting you ?U talking about which post?

Comment: you can also check if the json_decode returns null, that means there is a problem with the actual decoding (but the json you posted decodes fine). You can then run json_last_error() to find out what the problem is

Comment: When I am getting that printed json string and passing that to the function its decoding that string.

Comment: I would add to the scrip error reporting to make sure it not break somewere before the decoding error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Have you called [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)? It may turn out that you have an encoding problem?

Comment: it is showing this error:    PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Application\Controller\json_last_error_msg() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sandhya

Comment: That is because you're using PHP < 5.5. In this case use [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). If the function returns something different than 0 you'll have to look into [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php#106644) to decipher the int value...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this example:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "Error": {
        "name": "Email Unavailable",
        "message": "Email is already taken. Please choose different email.",
        "code": 202
    },
    "status": "False",
    "requestId": null
}';

$info = json_decode($json, true);

echo "Error - Name: {$info['Error']['name']}<br>"; 
echo "Error - Message: {$info['Error']['message']}<br>"; 
echo "Error - Code: {$info['Error']['code']}<br>"; 
echo "Status: {$info['status']}<br>"; 
echo "RequestId: {$info['requestId']}<br>"; 
?>
```

Output :

```
Error - Name: Email Unavailable
Error - Message: Email is already taken. Please choose different email.
Error - Code: 202
Status: False
RequestId:
```

Comment: I dont wants to pas the string .I wants to pass the response that u can see as $curl_response

Comment: @SandhyaGor just use $json = curl_exec($curl); and use the other part

Comment: @SandhyaGor you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

To check if you decode works fine you can run this code:

```
$json = '{"Error":{"name":"Email Unavailable","message":"Email is already taken. Please choose different email.","code":202},"status":"False","requestId":null}';     
print_r(json_decode($json, TRUE));
```

If theres is an error decoding in your code, json_decode will return null, you can check for this, and run [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: if I am doing like this its working but its not working when I am passing the response of API

Comment: Ok, then maybe its some encoding or some erraneous characters that get stripped when you post the string here. What if you print json_last_error() in your code when its not working?

Comment: @SandhyaGor make sure your API's output is utf-8 encoded

Answer (score 0):

There could be a curl error. If this is the case, curl_exec returns false. 
Also check for json_decode errors.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

```
$service_url = 'http://localhost:8888/ffmobile/signup';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array('email' => $this->params()->fromPost('email'), 'password' => $this->params()->fromPost('password'), 'userName' => $this->params()->fromPost('uname'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if($curl_response === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
    $response = json_decode($curl_response, TRUE);
    curl_close($curl);
    if( is_null($response) ) {
        echo 'json_decode error: ' . json_last_error();
    } else {
        // everything OK, do something with the response
    }
}
```